# OpenCV: how to convert all pixels outside of mask to transparent?

Tags: android, opencv, contour, opencv3.0

I have a 4 channels mask named maskMat colored in red (but I could choose any other color if required).

I have a 4 channels image named imageMat.

I want to set all the pixels of mat that are outside of maskMat to transparent color (in order to keep just the part of imageMat located in maskMat area).

How can I do that with OpenCV ? (I use openCV Java but an answer in any language will be ok)

Thanks.

Comment: Please either provide representative images showing both inputs and outputs, or provide  a few lines of code that will generate representative images, else answerers waste their time guessing what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: 1. convert image to 4 channel witg cvtColor(BGR2BGRA); 2. for every pixel: if mask(pixel) not set: set pixel value to (b,g,r,0)

Comment: @Micka I would not recommend loops and individually touching pixels. this can be done trivially with masked operations. besides, the question already states that matrices are 4-channel, so your suggestion of cvtColor makes no sense.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz: I waa too lazy to read the question again. Convertin to BGRA can easily be skipped but is a hint for others searching with a similar question. The loop version is simple to understand. Solution with .setTo would change the pixel values in addition to the transparency. Solution with bitwise operations will need the mask to be converted to 4-channel and makes operations less efficient and more complicated. In C++ looping is not that inefficient. Why don't you just write an answer?

Comment: @Regis_AG I could give you an answer in python but that will use numpy for most operations. you would have to use OpenCV's documentation on cv::Mat... please look up the documentation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution using bitwise_and. Here is my code:

```
Mat maskMat = .... // A RGBA Mat with mask in white color
Mat imageMat = .... // A RGBA Mat
Mat removedBlackMat = new Mat();
Core.bitwise_and(imageMat, maskMat, removedBlackMat);
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my inaccurate question!

Hope this will help somebody.